# Start Activity from Service in Android 10

Tags: java, android, firebase-in-app-messaging

please note that problem might be related to Android 10

Im trying to start a new Activity from myInAppMessagingService, but i got null pointer exception un startActivitys context parameter every time.

So here is my Service code :

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener;
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.model.Action;
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.model.CampaignMetadata;
import com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.model.InAppMessage;

import viaapp_v2.systems.webview_activity.webview_base;

public class MyFirebaseInAppMessaging extends Service implements FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener {

    String TAG = "MyFirebaseInAppMessaging";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageClicked(@NonNull InAppMessage inAppMessage, @NonNull Action action) {
        // Determine which URL the user clicked
        String url = action.getActionUrl();
        Log.d(TAG, "Popup URL :"+url);

        // Get general information about the campaign
        CampaignMetadata metadata = inAppMessage.getCampaignMetadata();
        Log.d(TAG, "metadata :"+metadata);

        try{
            startActivity(
                    new Intent(MyFirebaseInAppMessaging.this, webview_base.class)
                            .putExtra("web_url", url)
            );
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I got error in "startActivity(..)" line because of 1st parameter, context. I tried everything - getApplicationContext(), MyFirebaseInAppMessaging.this or just simply "this" but nothing works.

I read a [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) provided by Android Developers, but i couldnt figure out anything new.

Otherwise the app works perfectly - webview_base class works as it should, so does everything else, including myInAppMesaging Services listener. Its just that one context in startActivity() which stops me.

Thanks for any help.

--Update on Sep 7

After playing around with permissions, flags ect. i noticed that nothing works. Newer Android OS opens an web overly over the app, but older Android OS just crashes without any specific crash report. Thats weird.

Comment: If `this` does not work, then your code snippet is not a method in a `Service`. I recommend that you post the entire service class, not just one method from one nested object inside of it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, sorry, i updated the post with the full code from service class.

Comment: You should be able to just use `this`, in terms of your apparent compile error. At runtime, though, this will not work on Android 10+. Please display a notification!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code , it will work..

you have to add FLAG- `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, webview_base.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Just tried that, it didnt work. But i should use it there anyway to support devices under Android 10, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not visible and has not been visible for a while and you don't want to use a notification, it will not be allowed in Android 10, except if

> The app has been granted the [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission by the user.

(From the [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) page mentioned in the question)

So that's an option for Android 10.

Comment: I added ALERt_WINDOW permission in manifest, but i couldnt get the popup URL working anyways. Maybe you can provide an example or something else that could lead me into right path of coding.

Comment: Maybe i missed the part "granted" of permission which also means that i have to request user permissions ?

Comment: Yes, read the documentation from the link, it's even more strict because the user needs to manually activate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to list the **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** in AndroidManifest.xml. You also need user to give the app "Draw over other apps" permission. [Check here how to do that easily](https://localazy.com/blog/floating-windows-on-android-3-permissions).